# How to map a column twice with Hibernate with different type object

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity with two attributes, they are connected to another two entities with **@ManyToOne** relations. The first refers a single column, the second have a composite primary key that insists on the same column.

I would like that during insert, when the entity with the composite primary key is null, the other entity valorize the column, but it doesn't.
I'm looking for annotations that help me to map the relation.

Allegato:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="allegato", schema="schema")
@NamedQuery(name="Allegato.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Allegato a")
public class Allegato extends BaseEntity  {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="ide_allegato")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "allegato_seq", sequenceName = "allegato_seq", schema = "schema", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "allegato_seq")
private Integer ideAllegato;

//other attributes

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ide_scheda", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Scheda scheda;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ide_norma", referencedColumnName="ide_norma"),
    @JoinColumn(name="ide_scheda", referencedColumnName="ide_scheda")
    })
private SchedaNorma schedaNorma;
```

Scheda:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="scheda", schema="schema")
@NamedQuery(name="Scheda.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Scheda s")
public class Scheda extends BaseEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="ide_scheda")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "scheda_seq", sequenceName = "schema.scheda_seq", schema = "schema", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "scheda_seq")
private Integer ideScheda;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="scheda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SchedaNorma> schedaNormas;

@OneToMany(, mappedBy="scheda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Allegato> allegatos;

//other attributes
```

SchedaNorma (association table for entity Scheda and entity Norma):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="scheda_norma", schema="schema")
@NamedQuery(name="SchedaNorma.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM SchedaNorma s")
public class SchedaNorma extends BaseEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private SchedaNormaPK id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="schedaNorma")
private List<Allegato> allegatos = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ide_scheda" , insertable=false,updatable=false)
private Scheda scheda;
```

SchedaNormaPK:

```
@Embeddable
public class SchedaNormaPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="ide_scheda")
private Integer ideScheda;

@Column(name="ide_norma")
private Integer ideNorma;
```

When I insert Allegato and SchedaNorma is valorized everything is ok, but if SchedaNorma is null Hibernate (obviously) set value of column ide_scheda to null.